# Magento2 3 2 : How to Upload Product images To Amazon S3 Server After Product Save

Tags: product, magento2.3.2, media, amazon, s3

Does anyone know how can we upload product images to amazon s3 server 
after Product save?

Comment: Hi is this working for the latest version of magento 2 or not? 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thai's S3 Extension for Magento 2.

https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3

It will sync your images on S3 whenever you'll add / update product image.

Comment: yes i have check and it uploads image to s3 server m233 but it is not working in m232

Comment: If it's working for `m2.3.3` and not working for `m2.3.2` then something is wrong with your code. may be any other extension is doing conflict. Please check magento and server logs.

Comment: Also try to disable other extensions.

Comment: i already try by disable all other extensions and i got "Cannot resize image "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento232/pub/media/catalog/product/d/o/download55.jpg" error

Comment: Hello @SanjayShiyal did you got any solution for this?

Comment: And did it work for 232

Comment: yes @Arjun i got the solution

Comment: you need to override file : \Magento\MediaStorage\Service\ImageResize.php file becuase some function is not there in This file so just compare this file with m233 , you will find your problem's solution

Comment: Thanks @SanjayShiyal. It was really great of yours. You saved my day. One last thing are u facing any issue using Thai's extension in 232. I am planning to make it on my live site.

Comment: @Arjun  other things working okay with m232